# Performing operations at defined periods?

Tags: python, loops, time, args

I have problem with my script which is counting average mean from database.

Here is the code:

```
import MySQLdb
import argparse
import time

#args section
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-i", "--ip", required=True)
parser.add_argument("-r", "--ram", action="store_true", required=False)
parser.add_argument("-c", "--cpu", action="store_true", required=False)
parser.add_argument("-t", "--time", type=int, required=True)

args = parser.parse_args()

db1 = MySQLdb.connect(args.ip ,user="root",passwd="root")
cursor = db1.cursor()
use_db = "USE env_data;"

starttime = time.time()

def one_min():
        one_minute = time.sleep(60.0 - ((time.time() - starttime) % 60.0))
        return one_minute


def cpu_usage():
        cpu_select = "SELECT cpu_usage FROM env_data;"
        cpu_avg = "SELECT SUM(cpu_usage) / count(cpu_usage) from env_data;"

        cursor.execute(use_db)
        cursor.execute(cpu_select)
        cursor.execute(cpu_avg)
        result = cursor.fetchall()

        result = str(result)    #converted to string for replace operations
        for i in ['(',')',',', "'",'[', ']']:
                if i in result:
                        result = result.replace(i, '' )

        print result


def ram_usage():
        mem_select = "SELECT mem_usage FROM env_data;"
        mem_avg = "SELECT SUM(mem_usage) / count(mem_usage) from env_data;"

        cursor.execute(use_db)
        cursor.execute(mem_select)
        cursor.execute(mem_avg)
        result = cursor.fetchall()

        result = str(result)
        for i in ['(',')',',', "'",'[', ']']:
                if i in result:
                        result = result.replace(i, '' )

        print result

if args.cpu:
        cpu_usage()
elif args.ram:
        ram_usage()
```

User needs to type `--time` argument to define the time delay. For example:

```
my_script.py -i localhost -c -t 60
```

I need to have three periods - 1 / 15 / 60 minutes.

How I should to write it properly without using many `if` statements?

Comment: So you want to run an operation multiple times with a delay between each one? If so, couldn't you just use `time.sleep()` to delay between each iteration. Also, when is your script supposed to halt?

Comment: you can use `string.translate` to delete the characters  `string.translate(s, table[, deletechars])

    Delete all characters from s that are in deletechars (if present), and then translate the characters using table, which must be a 256-character string giving the translation for each character value, indexed by its ordinal. If table is None, then only the character deletion step is performed.`

Comment: Or you could do string formatting, since the `cursor.fetchall()` returns a list of tuples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accept all there intervals as command line arguments and just loop over them or, if they somehow are related and can be derived from one another, write a function that does the conversion.